# Parsing JSON in Java when two fields are the same?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup, json

Apologies, I have tried multiple things here and seem to run into some issues. This should be simple.

JSON file :

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "media_type": "text/html",
      "text": "<p>Hello world</p>"
    },
    {
      "media_type": "text/plain",
      "text": "Hello world"
    }
  ],
  "id": "123",
  "title": "no-title"
}
```

I have a JSONObject created from this string.

I have tried -

```
String txtFromJSON = json.getJSONObject("content").getJSONObject("text").toString();


String txtFromJSON = json.getString("content.text");

String txtFromJSON = json.getString("content");
```

All of these fail.

The output I would like is simply the

> `<p>Hello world<p>`

from the first text field.

Is there any simple way for me to get this data stored in a variable?

Thanks.

Comment: `content` is an array, not an object - it sounds like you should be using `getJSONArray`. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it easier to help you though.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(youJsonString);
final JSONObject content = obj.getJSONArray("content");
final int n = content.length();
if(n ==1 ){

String txtFromJSON = json.getString("text");

}
```

Comment: Why should they try that? What difference does it make? Why was their code wrong to begin with?

Comment: Agree with @SotiriosDelimanolis You provide absolutely no content to your answer as to why you think it is valid secondly your answer is completely wrong.

Comment: In this line String txtFromJSON = json.getString("content"); he try to get an Array, but he wants to receive only the string "Hello world" of the first text field (json.getString("text");).

Comment: Add that and all other details _to your answer_.